# CMake: How to add .def file to Visual Studio project filters?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, project, projects-and-solutions, function

How to add .def file to Visual Studio project filters (`*.filters` file)?
Visual Studio consumes .def file.

CMake code:

```
set(a_src a.cpp a.def)
add_library(a SHARED ${a_src})
```

In solution and then in project there is no `a.def` file in filters, only a.cpp. But CMake generates a rule for .def file (/DEF:a.def option to linker).

Is there any way to show .def files in the project filters (`a.filters` file near the project)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CMake bug.
It is reported in their tracker at http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15313