# CMake: How to add a .def file which is not a module definition file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

My company uses .def to store some symbol definitions (ASCII text file). We are using `CMake` to create `Visual Studio` solutions. We would like to have those def files be visible from `Visual Studio` for easier editing.

When I create a library like that:

```
set(a_src a.cpp a.def)
add_library(a SHARED ${a_src})
```

`Visual Studio` solution file browser only show `a.cpp`. `a.def` is present in `vcxproj` file, but like that: `<ModuleDefinitionFile>a.def</ModuleDefinitionFile>`, and it then does not appear in the solution file browser.

Is there any way to tell `CMake` or `Visual` that my def file is not a module definition file and should be treated as regular text file?

Comment: Did you check [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469926/cmake-how-to-add-def-file-to-visual-studio-project-filters)? It looks very similar to yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the property of the .def file after adding it:

```
set(a_src a.cpp a.def)
add_library(a SHARED ${a_src})
set_source_files_properties(a.def PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)
```

This makes the file visible in VS (tested on VS2013)

For reference: https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=7835